# Webdriver test - pushing events/notification to the test

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Here's the situation:

we run webdriver tests (python) testing a fat-client (Javascript) application. When the application is faced with an error (typically: backend does not respond/responds wit FAILURE) it shows an "We've got a problem" UI.

Currently, when this happens, the webdriver test just times-out:

a/ the test carries out some interaction

b/ the application responds with the said "we've got a problem" UI

c/ the test scans the DOM looking for some elements which should appear if the interaction succeeds

d/ as these DOM elements are not there the test repeats step c/ until it times-out

of course, we can explicitly write some code in the test that looks for the error-notification UI. However, we will have to call it from multiple places in our tests (and we're likely to miss several spots, etc.)

what we are looking for is something along these lines:

when running under webdriver the app will not show the error UI but instead invoke some API which will essentially "notify" the webdriver test that an error has occurred. On the test side, we'll register a listener on this notification. when fired, the listener will immediately make the test fail.

Essentially we are looking for an event dispatching API from the application side to the webdriver test side.

Does webdriver offer such an API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. Webdriver has an API for a busy wait (denoted [Implicit Waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)).

One suggestion that could slightly prettify this is using mini "sdk"s on both sides, but I'm not sure if Webdriver supports multithreading (two queries simultaneously) i.e.

1. Client side adds the predefined element in case there's an error.
2. Test side spawns a new thread and uses an implicit wait on the pre-decided element (added only in case of an error). Once he finds the element (meaning there's an error, where one of the fields comprises the error message), interrupts the test thread with the error.

See [similar example here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1682BnhVsmBudDkHWN_Bj_WAZ2iEJTwLwkHOnpYyP1Ac/edit?pli=1#slide=id.g339868958_1170).