# Webdriver test - pushing data from the app (Javascript) to the test (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

TL;DR: In a webdriver test can I pass some data from JS code running in the tested app the test code (written in Python)?

Situation:
when the application hits an error state I want it to pass some basic details about the error (things like: stacktrace, error message, etc.) to the webdriver test code to be used, for instance, in assertion messages, in the test.

One way to do that is to add a dummy, invisible, DOM element and to store that data (say) as this element's text. However, this seems kind of hackish. I was wondering whether there's a webdriver API providing  functionality along these lines:

- allowing the app to pass in `<key,value>` pairs
- allowing the test to lookup a value by key

In some sense this is a followup to the [Webdriver test - pushing events/notification to the test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380309/webdriver-test-pushing-events-notification-to-the-test) question. The main difference is that here I am looking for a webdriver API to support polling by the test code, where as in the previous question I was looking for an API to support event passing.